# Spring 4.3.6 Can't inject bean into controller

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test

I'm unable to put data in model because Spring doesn't wire bean to controller, reference is `null`. Bean interface and implementation in same package as controller. I tried to list available beans through implementing `ApplicationContextAware` in controller(also tried in test with output to console in method `setApplicationContext`, but method doesn't invoked, there was no output) but it's also `null`. I use automatic configuration, implementation of interface which used as a bean annotated with `@Component`, `@ComponentScan` enabled in servlet config class. This is controller:

```
package webapp.mvc;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryAware;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;



@Controller
public class HomeController implements ApplicationContextAware {

    public QuoteResource quoteResource;


    public ApplicationContext context;

    public HomeController() {
    }

    @Autowired
    public HomeController(QuoteResource resource) {
        this.quoteResource = resource;
        System.out.println("Constructor with resource triggered");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(){
        System.out.println("Controller triggered");
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/random", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String randomQuotes(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("randomQuote", quoteResource.getQuote());
        return "random";
    }

    @Autowired
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.context = applicationContext;      
    }

}
```

When I launch test is prints "Resource is null:
true
Start test
Constructor with resource triggered"
and fails with `nullPointerException` in line `model.addAttribute("randomQuote", quoteResource.getQuote());`
This is test:

```
package spr1;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView;

import webapp.mvc.HomeController;
import webapp.mvc.QuoteResource;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.*;


public class RandomQuoteTest {

    @Autowired
    public QuoteResource resource;

    @Before
    public void initObjects() {
        System.out.println("Resource is null:");
        System.out.println(resource == null);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Start test");
        HomeController controller = new HomeController(resource);
        MockMvc mvc = standaloneSetup(controller)
                .setSingleView(new InternalResourceView("src/main/webapp/views/random.jsp"))
                .build();
        mvc.perform(get("/random"))
        .andExpect(view().name("random"));
    }

}
```

`QuoteResource` is interface with one implementation which annotated with `@Component`, but it's constructor doesn't invoked(I write to console in constructor)

Comment: Looks like it is a configuration failure. Where have you configure the component-scan?

Comment: In servlet config  class i have `@ComponentScan` along with `@Configuration` and `@EnableWebMvc`

Comment: Please add it to the question, because it is important to answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `@Autowired` doesn't work in mvc tests. It works if controller created manually `HomeController controller = new HomeController(new XmlQuoteResource());` without autowiring QuoteResource. Found solution in spring-mvc-showcase in redirect example.